# Bibtex: I would like a comma instead of a period after a "PhD thesis" in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex

In the following MWE, I would like the citation to appear as

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvgfX.png) J. Doe. “Foo”. PhD thesis, Some University, 2000.

That is, I would like a comma instead of a period after the "PhD thesis". 
Is that possible?

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@phdthesis{foo,
 title={Foo},
 author={Doe, John},
 year={2000},
 school={Some University}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{references}
\begin{document}
I cite \cite{foo}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This results to the following

[image: Result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a patch:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{thisreference.bib}
@phdthesis{foo,
 title={Foo},
 author={Doe, John},
 year={2000},
 school={Some University}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{thisreference.bib}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{thesis}{%
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
}{%
  \printfield{type}%
  \newunit
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}
}{}{}

 \begin{document}
I cite \cite{foo}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]